# Mallet Document Classification - Reduce Vocabulary Size

Tags: java, memory, document-classification, mallet

I trained a maxent document classification model with Mallet and it turned out to be 130MB which is too large for the instance I wish to run it on.  I was wondering if there was a way to potentially reduce the vocabulary size of the model such that the overall model size would be reduced.  Is there a pipe for doing this?  The pipes that I am currently using are

```
 Pipe instancePipe = new SerialPipes(new Pipe[]{
            new Target2Label(),                     //creates labels
            new Input2CharSequence("UTF-8"),        //read the file as string
            new CharSequence2TokenSequence(),       //tokenize the string
            new TokenSequenceLowercase(),           //lowercase the tokens
            new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords(false),  //remove stopwords
            new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence(),    //convert tokens to features
            new FeatureSequence2FeatureVector(),    //create feature vector
            //new PrintInputAndTarget()  //print everything
    });
```

Any other tips for reducing model size would also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to try pruning the vocabulary after your initial import. Use

```
bin/mallet prune --help
```

to see options.